# What does “Blood money becomes bloodied money” mean?

Tags: meaning

There was the following sentence in New York Time’s (January 9) movie review of “Cold comes the night” that came under the title, “She’s hard as nails, he’s noir and nasty”:
http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/10/movies/cold-comes-the-night-starring-bryan-cranston-and-alice-eve.html

> “The opening image of a snow globe can’t help but suggest “Citizen
>   Kane,” while some gore-slicked bills may bring to mind “The Grifters”
>   or another literal-minded entertainment in which **blood money becomes
>   bloodied money**.”

I understand blood money means money paid to a hired murderer(s), but I don’t know “bloodied money.”

How different is “bloodied money” from “blood money” and “bloody money”? Is “bloodied money" a synonym of the preceding "gore-slicked bills"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is “bloodied money" a synonym of the preceding "gore-slicked bills"?

Yup. The idea is that *The Grifters* is "literal-minded entertainment" because the blood money ends up literally covered in blood. (They're not necessarily *exact* synonyms, in that the "gore-slicked bills" are in *Cold Comes the Night* and the "bloodied money" is in *The Grifters*, but the former "may bring to mind" the latter, so apparently they're in the same general vein.)

Answer (score 2):

Figurative language, in comparison with literal language, uses exaggerations or alterations to  emphasize a particular linguistic point. Figurative language is very common in poetry, and is also widely used in prose and nonfiction writings as well.

In this context, the gist of the sentence seems pretty straight forward. However individual interpretations may/may not/can dwindle.

As you have deduced, [blood money](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blood+money?s=t) could mean an Assassin's remuneration and bloodied money refers to money soiled with blood ( *figurative* association).